# how do i detect the output of failed files using requirejs optimizer

Tags: node.js, requirejs

At the moment the output shows syntactical errors in the files but saids skipping it.  How can I get it to fail on these files instead and how can detect output error codes for build automation purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That "skipping" error should only for when trying to uglify/minify the file. Since the minification is seen as an optional thing, not a fatal error. It is common for some projects to keep "JS fragments" in a file that are used as part of some concatenation approach.

So currently there is no way to stop on those errors. If you wanted, pass "optimize=none" to the build command to skip the minification, and manually do it with your tool of choice, and with that one, you could probably stop on errors.

If the errors are showing up in code that should not have syntax errors, doing a pre-build lint command using jslint or jshint is recommended.